# How to use PrimeNG p-fileUpload without multipart/form-data?

Tags: primeng

I'm using p-fileUpload to upload a .zip file into AWS S3, the upload works and I can download and open the file correctly by the OS application, but when I tried to read the same file using an InputStream Java, it doesn't work so well, e.g.

```
try (InputStream in = new URL(uri).openStream()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);

        return ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new SomeException(ex);
    }
```

Inspecting the file I see the following data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryhrGInEllRBnFuzls
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyAwesomeFunction970"; filename="hello-lambda.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

PK
�0E��w�DA����D:5t�)��
�w�l����\1�)bvs۠�)�ĺ���>DYa#f��&��U�p�mC�GS�i��<n���$�p3ux����

------WebKitFormBoundaryhrGInEllRBnFuzls--
```

The data above has some headers information and things that seems to be part of a multipart/form-data upload.

If I put the file through Postman, for example, the data is a little different (without the headers) and then works well via InputStream Java code.

```
PK
�0E��w�DA����D:5t�)��
�w�l����\1�)bvs۠�)�ĺ���>DYa#f��&��U�p�mC�GS�i��<n���$�p3ux����
```

Anyone knows what's happening with the upload process and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out this problem by calling a custom upload method, e.g:

```
<p-fileUpload
    name="{{uploadFileName}}"
    url="{{uploadUrl}}"
    customUpload="true"
    (uploadHandler)="customUpload($event.files, uploadUrl)">
</p-fileUpload>

customUpload(files:any, uploadUrl:string) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('PUT', uploadUrl, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', files[0].type);
        xhr.send(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct, if you want to keep the ui "functional", you might want to change the "uploading" and "progress" properties of the file upload component.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/fileupload/fileupload.ts#L399

```
<p-fileUpload
    #fileUpload
    name="{{uploadFileName}}"
    url="{{uploadUrl}}"
    customUpload="true"
    (uploadHandler)="customUpload($event.files)">
</p-fileUpload>

  import { FileUpload } from 'primeng/fileupload';

  @ViewChild('fileUpload') public fileUpload!: FileUpload;

  public uploadHandler(files: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const uploadUrl = this.uploadUrl;
    this.fileUpload.uploading = true;
    reader.onload = (evt: any) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('PUT', uploadUrl, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', files[0].type);
      xhr.addEventListener('error', () => {
        this.fileUpload.progress = 0;
        this.fileUpload.uploading = false;
      });
      xhr.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
        this.fileUpload.progress = 0;
        this.fileUpload.uploading = false;
      });
      xhr.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {
        if (e.loaded) {
          this.fileUpload.progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
        }
      });
      xhr.send(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
  }
```